# Angular 6 - Delete data from MongoDB, Typescript

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript, angular6

This is my HTML

```
  <tr *ngFor="let list of doclists;">
  <td>{{list.id}}</td>
  <td>{{list.name}}</td>

  <td>
    <button (click)="delete(list)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Typescript

```
delete(list) {
console.log('value to delete', JSON.stringify(list));    
this.deleteservice.deletelist(list.id).subscribe((data) => {
  this.doclists.splice(this.doclists.indexof(list), 1);      
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
}); }
```

Service

```
deletelist(list) {
let delete = this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/save`, list);
return delete; }
```

Here I am using the post endpoint to delete from MongoDB, kindly help me out with this delete operation. Thanks! in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are calling the method correctly.
I would refine it with an `actionType` attached to the body if you would like to keep it a post request
Otherwise, use DELETE method and pass the listId in the params, and pick it up in your server using `req.params.id`

**CLIENT SIDE**

*HTML:*

`<button (click)="delete(list)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>`

*TS:*

```
delete(LIST) {
  this.deleteservice.deletelist({list: LIST, actionType: 'DELETE').subscribe((data) => {
    this.doclists.splice(this.doclists.findIndex(list => list._id === LIST._id), 1);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
}); }
```

- Note the `findIndex` function which allows a mixure of a `map`ping function and an index finding function. It's more performative (instead of mapping all objects to object._id and then calling `indexOf` to find the index of a specific object by an ID (`indexOf` will not find you the object you are looking for by passing a full object as `Object === sameObject => false`
- Note the param passed into the `deleteList` method. You can either set it by pure string, or make use of the convinience `enums` offer:

  ```
  export enum LIST_ACTIONS {
    CREATE, // translates to 0 
    DELETE, // translates to 1,
    ANOTHER_ACTION = 100, // translates to 100
    YET_ANOTHER_ACTION // translates to 101
  }

  this.deleteService.deleteList({list: listID, actionType: ACTION_TYPES.DELETE})
  ```
- Also, it would be safer to `findIndex` first and then call `splice`: EX:

  ```
  const INDEX = array.findIndex(object => object._id === objectID);
  if (INDEX > -1) { array.splice(INDEX, 1); }
  ```

*SERVICE:*

Normally you would use `POST` to CREATE something, and `PATCH` or `PUT` to ALTER it (change properties of the doc). You can also use `POST` of course but that would not be very definitive. In case you do, a use of an ACTION_TYPE is required so the call does not mix with any other functions to the same route you are calling with the same `METHOD`:

```
deletelist(data: {list: List, actionType: ACTION_TYPES}) {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/save`, data);
}
```

**SERVER SIDE**

*ROUTER:*

`router.post('/api/save', myDocHandlingFunction)`

*CONTROLLER*

```
export function myDocHandlingFunction(req, res, next) {
  if (req.body.actionType === ACTION_TYPES.DELETE) {
    LIST_MODEL.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.list._id)
      .then(success => {
        res.status(200).json({message: 'Removed'})
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Did not remove'})
      })
  }
}
```

- NOTE: Remember to create an enum Object for the server side too. either by Typescript or using JS [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) method
- NOTE: By using a `POST` HTTP method, you declare you may not actually REMOVE the doc but actually alter it somehow. Perhaps by adding a property to the doc such as `removed: false`, and by "removing" it you actually change `removed` to `true` using `LIST_MODEL.findByIdAndUpdate(list._id, {removed: true}).then().catch()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I need to use the POST request itself, so could you please let me know how would you refine it with an "actionType"?

Comment: @vaibhav Yes I've added a full example

Comment: Thanks a lot you made my day!